# safety precautions of high tension wire during rainy season?

Tags: high-voltage

Hi what are the safety precautions of high tension wire during rainy season?

what is the precaution need to do, if the wire get cut and fallen in the road?

Comment: Move away. Hope that the distance to soil is much closer than you.    If less than  16meter frog jump away in case of gradient voltage on surface.

Comment: If you are in your car, stay inside until you are sure that the power has been disconnected.

Comment: call the emergency number on a cell phone

Comment: @Jasen they will also take some delay, is there any alternative to avoid it?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 it all happens suddenly means, how to avoid it?, every time have to jump?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electronic design.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, nothing. It'll blow and kill anybody until the overcurrent protection will disconnect the powerline. Even so, the overcurrent protection will automatically try for three times to reconnect again, just to make sure the short circuit is permanent.

Comment: Good point, automatic re-closers are often used on branch circuits to check if the fault was transient (wind or branch induced wire short or a lightning strike) and reconnect without having to send out a crew.  There can be a variable number of attempts depending on the type of network or country etc. etc.  2 or 3 are typical but don't assume a later attempt will not occur from a different branch or ring circuit later.

Comment: ya, we can assume automatic re-closer but not in all countries and when the rain stops, no one will think about the electricity, because there intention is to reach home. and finally, is there any materials or items to avoid it?

Comment: nothing practical, just say well clear, if you're in a car, stay inside it.